# Can a sorcerer spell cast from a magic item trigger a Wild Magic Surge?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, sorcerer, wild-magic

A Wild Magic Surge may happen when a [Wild Magic sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#WildMagic) (PHB, p. 103-104) casts a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher:

> Once per turn, the DM can have you roll a d20 immediately after you cast a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher. If you roll a 1, roll on the Wild Magic Surge table to create a magical effect.

Some magic items let you cast spells that are on the sorcerer spell list. For example, the [Staff of the Magi](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-the-magi) lets you cast [*enlarge/reduce*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce), which is a sorcerer spell.

Would casting a spell on the sorcerer spell list from a magic item have the potential of causing a Wild Magic Surge (for a Wild Magic sorcerer) ?

Comment: related: [Wild Magic Surge activation without using spell slots](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94891/wild-magic-surge-activation-without-using-spell-slots)

Comment: Related: [Does casting a spell from an item allow you to apply class abilities that are used when casting a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50054/does-casting-a-spell-from-an-item-allow-you-to-apply-class-abilities-that-are-us)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### It would appear that this is possible.

The rules do support this outright. Per PHB p102 (emphasis mine):

> Immediately after **you cast** a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher...

And from DMG p141 under "Spells" (emphasis mine):

> Some magic items allow **the user** to cast a spell from the item...

So if the item allows a sorcerer to cast a spell and that spell is on the sorcerer's list then your class feature would apply based on the wording. Also, see [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50054/does-casting-a-spell-from-an-item-allow-you-to-apply-class-abilities-that-are-us).

It seems as though rules designer Jeremy Crawford says this is the intent in [this tweet from May 2016](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/729792450395430913) note that [JC's Tweets are no longer official rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/with-the-2019-sage-advice-compendium-release-are-jeremy-crawfords-tweets-consi).:

> Q: when a wild magic sorcerer uses a wand of magic missiles, can he
> trigger a Wild Magic Surge?
>
> JC: Yes.

Keep in mind that a DM is free to ignore this as with anything else. Example: I could easily see a DM stating that your sorcerer's list is the one he *knows* not to include ones in the PHB under sorcerer that he does not.

Comment: A DM is free to ignore anything, so why the last sentence?

Comment: @András The occasional reiteration is always helpful.